# jQuery selectors diffusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have something like `.class` and I use this as the id of a div element:

```
<div id=".class">...</div>
```

But I can't use this selector:

```
$("#.class")...
```

If I remove the `.` before `class`, it is impossible because the `.class` comes from a dynamic code.

I want some way to force the string after `#` to be selective.

Perhaps the solution may look something like this:

```
<div id="<.class>"...
```

Comment: Escape it with \\ maybe ... And if it's not working it's because the id ".class" is not correct according [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

Comment: why not remove the dot programmatically?

Comment: Couple of things about your question:

1) id's can't start with `.`
2) there should be an = sign between `id` and `.class` like `<div id=".class"></div>`
3) given the = sign is in the right spot you could use something like this `$('div[id=".class"]')`